# Missing scheme (IllegalArgumentException) while using java.nio.file.Paths interface

Tags: java, eclipse, path, uri, nio

this is a really simple java question. I am using Java 8 with eclipse kepler on a linux system. I've been trying to try out NIO.2. My code is:

```
package lucasTest;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.nio.file.*;

public class Lucas {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException{
        URI u = new URI("./Lucas.java");
        Path p = Paths.get(u);  
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing scheme
    at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:134)
    at lucasTest.Lucas.main(Lucas.java:10)
```

Please help!

Thanks,
Lucas

Comment: A URI must have a scheme - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme for the file scheme.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your uri declaration is missing the scheme for files (`file:///`):

```
u = new URI("file:///./Lucas.java");
Path p = Paths.get(u);
```

should work. As an alternative you can try

```
 Path p2 = Paths.get(".", "Lucas.java");
```