# Java: Paths.get(URI) throws IllegalArgumentException but Paths.get(URI.toString) does not. Why?

Tags: java, path

I was using `URI` as a parameter for `Paths.get()`. I used it in other parts of my code, however, there is one path that could not be resolved. It threw an `IllegalArguementException: Missing Scheme`. The path name uses "/" and "-", however, those are not reserved characters.

So I tried using the SAME URI but as a string. So basically `Paths.get(destinationURI)` doesn't work but `Paths.get(destinationURI.toString)` does.

Does anyone understand why that is the case? I REALLY would like to know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it would be nice if you could show us the URI.

Comment: Look here at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25167149/missing-scheme-illegalargumentexception-while-using-java-nio-file-paths-interf. Every URI MUST have a scheme, and the URI must not be formed to be a file scheme.

Comment: How is the URI formed? What does destinationURI.getScheme() return?

Comment: I'll be more direct. If you don't show the URI you are unlikely to get a valid answer, and risk having the question closed for lack of required detail.

Comment: The url was similar to /data/communications/nb-1-1-201606271723466-data/somefilename.txt

Comment: Astrogeek, I did see that post before I found my solution. Am I required to put "file://" in front of my path? (From what I understood, other portions of my code did not. I may be mistaken though)